# How do I set up an App Script function to only email table rows that include "PASS" in them?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an function that sends an email if requested in the menu. The body of that email contains two columns. What I need is to only choose rows from the table that equal "PASS" in column C. How do I alter my function to do that?

```js
function SendEmail() {
    var data = rpt.getRange("B:C").getValues();
    //var htmltable =[];

    var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT + ' ">';

    for (row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

        htmltable += '<tr>';

        for (col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {
                htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';
            } else
            if (row === 0) {
                htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
            } else {
                htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
            }
        }

        htmltable += '</tr>';
    }

    htmltable += '</table>';
    Logger.log(data);
    Logger.log(htmltable);
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'Keyword Blueprint Report', '', {
        htmlBody: htmltable
    })
}
```

Comment: `if(data[row].join("").indexOf("PASS")>-1){send your email}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = rpt.getRange("B:C").getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var data = rpt.getRange("B1:C" + rpt.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([,c]) => c == "PASS");
```

Or, if you want to leave the 1st row (header row), you can also use the following script.

```
var data = rpt.getRange("B1:C" + rpt.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([,c], i) => i == 0 || c == "PASS");
```

- In this modification, the retrieved values are filtered.
- I thought that when the range is modified to `"B1:C" + rpt.getLastRow()`, the process cost will be reduced.

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you for this quick assist. This worked but it removed the header column that labels what column B and C are. How can I make sure that row 1 stays?

Comment: @Michael Brown Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @MegaMikeJr Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.